# Fachbegriff für plattdeutsche Wörter im Hochdeutsch

Tags: dialect, terminology, varieties, low-german

Für Besonderheiten der drei (nationalen) Hauptvarietäten des Deutschen gibt es die hinreichend etablierten Termini *Teutonismus* (DE), *Austriazismus* (AT) und *Helvetismus* (CH). Sie sind nützlich, wenn man über Unterschiede zwischen den Varietäten redet oder die Herkunft transnational etablierter Begriffe (wie bspw. *Anglizismus*) bezeichnen möchte.

Gibt es auch einen halbwegs gebräuchlichen Fachbegriff für Wörter aus dem Niederdeutschen, der spezifischer ist als *Regionalismus*? Vielleicht **Saxonismus*?

Wie bei den anderen genannten Begriffen geht es dabei sowohl um Wörter, die nur in norddeutscher Umgangssprache verwendet werden (z.B. *Trecker* statt *Traktor*), als auch um solche, die zwar aus dem Platt stammen, aber inzwischen allgemein gebräuchlich sind (z.B. *Wrack*).

Comment: Ich kann aktuell nicht erkennen, was *Lehnwort* mit den angeführten Regional-Spezialitäten zu tun hat. Ist jetzt ein Begriff für ein aus dem Plattdeutschen eingebürgtes Wort gefragt, oder eines, was nur in der plattdeutschen Sprachzone gebräuchlich ist?

Comment: Stimme @guidot zu: Geht es um Fälle wie _roden_ (aus dem Niederdeutschen stammende Lautform, die im ganzen Sprachgebiet das hochdeutsche _rotten_ verdrängt hat, abgesehen vom Kompositum _ausrotten_) oder um etwas wie _schnacken_, das im Süden nicht verwendet und möglicherweise nicht verstanden wird?

Comment: @guidot Ich habe _Lehn-_ aus dem Titel entfernt und einen Absatz am Ende hinzugefügt.

Comment: Gute Frage. Solche Wörter sind durchaus zahlreich, z.B. _Bagger, bekloppt, brackig, buddeln, diesig, doof, drillen, dröge, fies, Flagge, knuddeln, krabbeln, Krake, Krempe, krosch, kross, Lake, Laken, Müll, oll, pellen, popeln, pökeln, Qualm, rappeln, Robbe, sabbern, scheel, Schmöker, Stoppel, Tüte, verheddern, Watt_.

Answer (score 1):

Wenn es einen solchen Begriff gäbe, müsste es auch ähnliche Begriffe für Wörter aus anderen Dialekten geben. Das ist meines Wissens aber nicht der Fall.

Wenn nämlich ein Dialektwort in den Wortschatz einer Standardsprache aufgenommen wird, indem es z.B. in Zeitungen gedruckt oder von Nachrichtensprechern ausgesprochen wird, dann gehört es bereits zur Standardsprache. Wenn dies z.B. nur in Österreich der Fall ist, nicht jedoch in anderen deutschsprachigen Regionen, dann ist dieses Wort automatisch ein Austriazismus (z.B. »Sackerl«).

Schafft es ein ehemaliges Dialektwort mit vormals begrenztem Verbreitungsgebiet im gesamten deutschen Sprachraum in einem standardsprachlichen Kontext verwendet zu werden, dann gehört es dem gesamtdeutschen Standard an, und ist einfach ein deutsches Wort (»Jagertee«); selbst dann, wenn den meisten Sprecher die regionale mundartliche Vergangenheit bewusst ist.

Wenn hingegen ein Wort nicht in einem standardsprachlichen Kontext verwendet wird, dann stellt sich die Frage gar nicht, denn dann handelt es sich eben um einen Dialekt oder um Umgangssprache (z.B. »Bim« für »Straßenbahn« in Wien).

Man darf nämlich nicht vergessen, dass Teutonismen (z.B. »Abitur«), Austriazismen (»Marille«) und Helvetismen (»Automobilist«) keine Dialektwörter sind, sondern Wörter aus einer der drei *standardisierten* deutschen Hochsprachen.

»Standardisiert« heißt: Es gibt zusätzlich zum Wortschatz auch verbindliche Regeln zur Rechtschreibung und zur Grammatik. Man kann anhand dieses Regelwerks falsch geschriebene Wörter von richtig geschriebenen unterscheiden. Dasselbe gilt für richtig bzw. falsch gebaute Sätze.

Plattdeutsch bzw. Niederdeutsch gilt gemeinhin als Dialekt und nicht als eigenständige Sprache, obwohl es diesbezüglich auch gegenteilige Meinungen gibt. Plattdeutsch ist aber jedenfalls nicht standardisiert. Das heißt, es gibt keine festen Regeln, anhand derer man in jedem beliebigen Fall einen korrekten plattdeutschen Satz von einem falschen unterscheiden kann.

Zumindest in diesem Sinn ist Plattdeutsch ein Dialekt bzw. eine Gruppe von Dialekten, und ist somit mit Schweizerdeutsch oder den Bairischen Dialekten vergleichbar, und gehört somit einer anderen Kategorie an als Deutsches Deutsch, Österreichisches Deutsch und Schweizerisches (Hoch-)Deutsch.

Comment: Es finden sich durchaus Belege für bspw. _Alemannismus_ und _Bavarismus_ (bzw. _-en_), aber ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob es sich um etablierte Termini oder Adhoc-Prägungen handelt, die zudem nicht auf eine sprachliche Bedeutung beschränkt sind. Auch für _Saxonismus_, das ich spontan gebildet hatte, findet sich bspw. [diese Quelle](http://www.uni-protokolle.de/Lexikon/Regionalismen_%28Niedersachsen%29.html) (aus Wikipedia, aber da gelöscht) in ziemlich genau der gewünschten Bedeutung – anderswo wird es aber auch auf den sächsischen Dialekt bezogen.

Comment: Dafür dass Plattdeutsch gemeinhin ein Dialekt ist, bitte einen Beleg. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niederdeutsche_Sprache sagt anders

Comment: @arved: https://www.google.at/?gws_rd=ssl#q=Plattdeutsch+dialekt Da gibt es massenhaft Publikationen die den einen oder den anderen Standpunkt vertreten. Mein persönlicher Standpunkt ist der: Solange Schweizerdeutsch nicht als Sprache, sondern als Dialekt gilt, sollte das auch für Plattdeutsch gelten. Ich bezog mich in meinem Posting übrigens ausdrücklich auf die fehlende Standardisierung als Unterscheidungsmerkmal. Tatsächlich ist die Abgrenzung zwischen Sprache und Dialekt auch in vielen anderen Fällen strittig.

Comment: @arved: Ich zitiere aus der von dir selbst angeführten Quelle (de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niederdeutsche_Sprache unmittelbar vor dem Inhaltsverzeichnis): »**Folglich handelt es sich beim Niederdeutschen um einen Dialekt**, der in den niederen, das heißt nördlicheren Landen gesprochen wurde bzw. wird.« (Fette Hervorhebung von mir). Auch sonst wird im gesamten Artikel, mit Ausnahme der Überschrift und des ersten Satzes, Niederdeutsch durchgehend als Dialekt bezeichnet. Sogar das Wort »Platt« an sich soll laut diesem Artikel nichts anders als »Dialekt« bedeuten.

Comment: @arved: In dem Wikipedia-Artikel steht auch ein Abschnitt, der sich der Frage »Dialekt oder Sprache« widmet. Nach dessen Lektüre habe ich den Eindruck, dass diese Frage strittig ist, wobei eine schwache Mehrheit der Fachleute für den Dialekt-Status zu plädieren scheint. Und das stimmt ziemlich genau mit meinen Ausführungen in meiner Antwort überein. DOrt habe ich übrigens nicht behauptet, dass Plattdeutsch gemeinhin ein Dialekt **ist**, sondern **als solcher gilt**.